# Retrieve overseas order amount in USD via Google Checkout API

Tags: android, google-play, google-checkout, sales-analytics, store-reports

I have paid Android apps on Google Play. I'm using Google Checkout XML API (notification history, specifically) to retrieve order details. I'm in the USA, and some of my customers are not. For overseas orders, the Google Checkout API returns the order amount in native currency, not USD, and doesn't provide the exchange rate, either.

On the Google Checkout site, on the other hand, I can see the USD revenue amount in order details, and it matches the eventual payout perfectly. They display order total in native currency, then the fee, then my profit - first in native currency, then in dollars.

I'm afraid that if I'll use the native currency and apply one of the publicly available rates, the dollar amount will not match Google's. And reconciliation with the eventual payout would not be possible.

I've set the notification API version to 2.5. I'm retrieving every possible notification for an order. There's no USD amount that I can see, and no rate.

Short of scraping the Google Checkout web UI, any ideas, please?

[Link: someone else admitting the problem.](http://blog.rectangularsoftware.com/2013/01/improved-order-reconciliation-in-appmonger-2-3-1/)

EDIT: I actually had Checkout screen scraping as an interim solution. Then they've rolled out the new Wallet merchant page, and it became much less friendly to scraping :(

Comment: AFAIK, the GC API is for legacy (web site sales) implementations - not for Android/Play nor any other newer API. That said, as you have noticed, you *can* get data somehow though the (legacy) schema doesn't give you want you need. Payout API has been one of those things that I also have wished for (years) as that would probably solve your need. You can't use *current* exchange rates because its a "point in time" (when the order was placed) rate.

Comment: Play has no API that I know of, other than device-side licensing and in-app purchase API.